# How can I call a web service from NAnt

Tags: web-services, nant

The NAnt build system I am working on has a few <exec> tasks which essentially call EXEs that are wrappers around calls to a .NET web service. I would like to streamline things as much as possible, and it occurred to me that that if I could make a web service call directly from the NAnt script, that would eliminate one step. However, I can't find a task to do this. The nearest I can find is the <get> task. At the least, I would need a task called something like <post>.

Does anybody have a suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `<script language="C#">`.

http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.92/help/tasks/script.html

```
  <script language="C#">
      <code>
        <![CDATA[
          public static void postToWebservice() {
              ....
          }
        ]]>
      </code>
  </script>
```

---

```
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://WEB_URL");
myReq.Method = "POST";
myReq.ContentType = "text/xml";
myReq.Timeout = 30000;
myReq.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", ":\"#save\"");

byte[] PostData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDocument);
myReq.ContentLength = PostData.Length;

using (Stream requestStream = myReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(PostData, 0, PostData.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at [NAnt Contrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/help/tasks/). There are many really useful functions including some features for web services.

Comment: Yes, that is where I got <get> from. Sadly this is the nearest to what I want. Unfortunately,  I need to POST data to the web service.